# Extend the typeahead.js api

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I want to extend the existing api of typeahead.js. In the end I want to override the internal functions. Is there a standard way to do this?

This way I have tried but it will not allow me to alter anything:

```
(function(t){
    t.foo = function (){
        console.log("bar");
    }

})(window.jQuery.fn.typeahead);
```